# What is the difference between "then block" and "then handler" in javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecma

In the documentation of promises in javascript in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). It is written:

> using a resolved promise, the 'then' block will be triggered instantly, 
>        but its handlers will be triggered asynchronously

```
// using a resolved promise, the 'then' block will be triggered instantly, 
// but its handlers will be triggered asynchronously as demonstrated by the console.logs

var resolvedProm = Promise.resolve(33);

var thenProm = resolvedProm.then(function(value){
    console.log("this gets called after the end of the main stack. the value 
    received and returned is: " + value);
    return value;
});

// instantly logging the value of thenProm
console.log(thenProm);

// using setTimeout we can postpone the execution of a function to the moment 
// the stack is empty

setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(thenProm);
});

// logs, in order:
// Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
// "this gets called after the end of the main stack. the value received and returned is: 33"
// Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: 33}
```

I do not quite understand the part which it says the block will be triggered but handlers are triggered async. My questions are:

1. What is the then block? What is its handler and how do they differ ?
2. What triggers each?
3. When that async trigger happens, it is rosolved after all

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that sentence makes no sense. It was introduced in this edit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then$revision/1250601

Comment: I found nothing in the link, nor do I know what is a "then block/handler" but from my experience with promises, I can tell you that the code used in `then` is executed instantly as the promise gets resolved but asynchrony from the main stack. You should never base yourself in the order of asynchronous actions for making code.

Comment: "block" makes no sense, the term means something else. I can only assume that the wording is supposed to mean "the chunk of code containing the `then()` call is executed immediately".

Comment: @Bergi yeah that's a good point, if you don't mind I'll add this line to my answer?

Comment: @redFur Sure, go ahead

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is a bit confusing, here is my attempt at explaining what I think it means. Please don't hesitate to throw rocks at me if I got it wrong somewhere:)

`.then()` method returns a promise. I think by `the 'then' block will be triggered instantly` it is meant that the `.then` method is run in the current run of the event loop and will return the promise immediately. However, the callbacks that you pass to the `then` method get executed asynchronously, i.e., in the following run of the event loop.

So, in that example the first logged line is

> `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

because this:

```
var thenProm = resolvedProm.then(function(value){
    console.log("this gets called after the end of the main stack. the value 
    received and returned is: " + value);
    return value; });
```

is run and the promise is returned, but the callbacks that return the value are not yet executed so the value is undefined.

After the event loop run is finished, the next one begins and the callback gets executed. This callback assigns the value to the promise and logs this line:

> "this gets called after the end of the main stack. the value received
>   and returned is: 33"

Finally, the promise itself is logged, with the newly assigned value:

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: 33}

To answer your questions more directly then:

1. `Then` is a method on Promise, that takes a callback function(s) and returns another promise. That function will then be fired when the original promise is resolved.
2. When the original promise gets resolved or rejected, that is what triggers the callback function passed in the 'then' method. Nothing "triggers" `.then()` method itself, it's just a method.
3. The resolving of the promise is what triggers the callback.

As @Bergi said, a big source of confusion is probably the word "block", which here probably simply means "the chunk of code inside the `.then` method call."

Answer (score 0):

1. Then block is the method of Promise object.It used  for registering callbacks, which  will be called in case Promise fulfilled or rejected.
2. First triggers in time  when you create a Promise instance. Handler will be called when Promise will be  resolved or rejected